# Oracle SQL Developer database diff doesn’t list my connections

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I’m trying to perform a Diff on two DB2 schema’s and when I try to select my source and destination connections it doesn’t list my NEW connection. I’m using latest version. I can connect to DB2 manually and query as well, but just can’t sect that connection during database Diff.

Where are the connections saved in sql
Developer?

Comment: Diff on non-oracle is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is reserved for Oracle Database connections.

DB2 connectivity is provided for migrations to Oracle only.

We have limited support for DB2 in the Data Modeler (which is part of SQL Developer), and you can compare models, but the generation of DDL synch scripts is reserved for Oracle data models only.

[image]

Comment: Any other tools that can do on DB2. Please I periodically get new changes and I need to generate Delata script and move it to higher environments

Comment: there are lots of tools out there, most of them that do what you want, will cost $ - so make sure IBM doesn't offer something first

Comment: Try IBM Data Studio